# YOLO V8 save results custom file name

Tags: pose-estimation, yolov8, pose

I want to save the results the prediction of Yolo v8.
I know how so set the path or project/name but I don't want just any file name, e.g. "image0.jpg". I want to specify the file name to something like "custom-name.jpg".
I want to iteratively detect human pose on a number of images from a directory.

```
model = YOLO("./yolov8x-pose.pt")
for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
  img = cv2.imread(file)
  results = model(source=img, save=True, project='/../place')
```

I want to specify the file names of the results in the folder, to either the original file name or something close.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was first reading the image file with cv2 `img = cv2.imread(file)`.
Solution:
`results = model(source=file, save=True, project='../place')`
YOLO will read the source file directly and use the filename in the results.